# How to have cascading inserts?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I hope my request is clear. I will try and be as informative as possible.

I have a form that has a Tabular Form Control

The Parent Form holds Student data. The Record Source is

```
SELECT * FROM Students WHERE Period = 1
```

This Parent Form holds a Tabular Form Control. The Tabular Form has 3 pages:

```
Reading Writing Math
```

With each of these pages (Reading, Writing, Math), I want to have a Subform.

So, the data for the Parent form pulls Student data and it looks like this:

```
Student ID 
Name
```

What I want the Subforms to look like is this. For Reading:

```
Student ID
Favorite Book
```

Writing

```
Student ID
Words Per Minute
```

Math

```
Student ID
Highest Level
```

I would like for the Student ID to be automatically populated. So the Student Form will look like

```
 Student ID    Name
    1          'Mark'
```

And the Reading Form will look like

```
Student ID     Favorite Book
    1             Harry Potter
```

I have a Reading table, a Writing one, and a Math table as well. So I would like for these values to populate each table.

I hope this makes sense. I have a relationship between the Student ID from the Student table and the three tables.

In summary, I would like for a child Subform that is hosted in a Tabular Form to access a column from the Root level and bind that column to the child.

Comment: Cascading inserts do not exist (unlike cascading deletes). You will have to write all the steps in code to manage the IDs. A handy way sometimes is to use a stored procedure so that from you program it is a single call and easily managed transaction

Comment: If your "child" tables all have identical (?) structure, something might be wrong with the modelization. If you ever need similar data for `Sociology`, do you need to create a new *record* somewhere, or a whole new *table*?

Comment: That said, something like "cascading inserts" *can* be achieved with *triggers*, but I don't think Access supports that... but triggers are generally regarded as sloppy anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You use Child tables (and subforms for their presentation), when you have 0..many records that are linked to a master record.

E.g. a student has read n books, or has visited m math courses with m grades.
Then you insert the child records when there is data, not in every table at once.

If you only want to store **one** favorite book or **one** math level per student, these should be **columns** in your students table. Not separate tables.

If you want to show the favorite of many books (by whatever metric), or the highest math grade, then these are **query results** from the child tables.

In neither of these cases do you need to insert one record into each of the child tables at once.

---

Now if your actual data is much more complex, and there is actual need for a one-to-one relation of master and child table(s), then you must create all these records at once in one function or stored procedure, using multiple insert statements.

But these cases are rare.